# Can someone suggest a hardware barcode scanner that will work with Titanium Developer?

Tags: ios, ios4, titanium, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am looking for a hardware barcode scanner which is preferably wireless that can be interfaced with Titanium Developer.

I understand that the camera can be used to achieve this, however our requirement is for a field environment where it will not be uncommon for > 1,000 repeated scans to be performed so it has to be fast (~200ms scan time).

We will require > 500 of these devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to build your own solution using any of the compatible hardware, Please look in to [Custom iOS module development](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/iphone/module_sdk)

Comment: Thanks rb, this may come in handy as the hardware will ultimately come down to a decision by management.

Comment: if your buying hardware for iOS make sure to look at the apple compatibility tag ...

Answer (score 0):

the bigest brands in the area are **Datalogic**

[QuickScan Wireless Scanner](http://www.scanning.datalogic.com/sitefiles/quickscanm.aspx)

and **Symbol** (now Motorola)

[CA50 Wireless Barcode Scanner](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Product+Lines/Symbol/Symbol+Bar+Code+Scanners/CA50_US-EN)

for compatibility against the software, you should send an email to Appcelerator Support